# Make a column editable according to specific value with Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

how can i make column editable according to a specific value in Model,

```
{ name: 'Name', field: 'Name', displayName: 'Name' , width :'100' @if (Model.RDOnly) { Html.Raw(@", enableCellEdit: false");}
```

i guess that HTML.Raw isn't the right one to use, any idea ?

thanks,

Comment: Angular.js or Angular2?

Answer (score 0):

Try- https://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/

for editing html tables.